# Maximize a piecewise function

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

I'm trying to linearize the problem:

$\max f(x)\\\text{s.t.}\\g(x)\geq 0$

Where $g(x)$ are already linear functions, but $f(x)$ is the following piecewise function:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
bx,  & \text{if } x < c \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if } x = c \\[2ex]
-ax, & \text{if } x>c
\end{cases}$

With $a,b,c>0$ constants.

This seems very easy, but I'm having a hard time to find a solution. So, I would be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce three binary variables, one for each piece, a constraint that they sum to 1, and additional linear constraints that link the binary variables to $f(x)$, but it is simpler to just solve three separate problems and take the max.

If $x\in[L,U]$ and $\epsilon>0$ is a tolerance, impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
z_1+z_2+z_3&=1\\ 
L z_1+c z_2+(c+\epsilon)z_3 \le x &\le (c-\epsilon)z_1+c z_2+U z_3\\
-M(1-z_1)\le f-b x &\le M(1-z_1)\\
-M(1-z_2)\le f&\le M(1-z_2)\\
-M(1-z_3)\le f+a x&\le M(1-z_3)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you Rob. I cannot solve them separately, because it is part of a scheduling problem, and the total cost is in fact the sum of T problems of this type. Therefore I think I must add the binary variables. I started modelling with one binary for each piece. However, I'm not sure how to link $f(x)$ to them. Something like: $f(x) = \lambda_1(bx) + \lambda_2(0) + \lambda_3(-ax)$? What about the limits $c$?

Comment: No, that would still be nonlinear because of the products of variables. I updated the answer just now.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!